# Looking for the title of a film / TV show with a young boy and slightly older girl vs. a circular room full of robots and a booming voice

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv, robots

The scene I remember was from a (maybe?) 70s TV show or a movie that showed a younger boy with a slightly older girl which I guess was a sister or a female friend, both wearing body suits, walking into a massive room.

It was a circular room, the walls were decorated in like the typical science fiction metallic walls you see in old SF movies, where robot men with hideously scowling faces were standing guard along the walls.

Then lights flash from the roof in sync with a booming voice that gives the kids a warm welcome to something. The boy has a brief chat with the voice, who they seem to recognize from somewhere else, to which the voice seems to be more slightly passively aggressive about and then a circular hatch opens in the middle of the room.

Slowly this towering circular thing rises up from the hole as the voice booms angrily before harshly ordering the robots guards to surround the thing with their backs turned against it, with this intense tube orchestra booms in the background.

The boy has a brief debate with the girl, who seems to be only communicating with sign language, debating and pondering about something.

Then, a male narrator starts to babble about this or that as it seems to cut to a cliffhanger, the scene cuts to a shot of space with stars flying past the camera while the voice talks until he yawns and tells that it is time to rest and lets get back to the show some other time. Cut to the credits with white fonts against a metallic wall with pipes and wires all over while this booming orchestral music with tubas and large drums plays.

Another clue I can recall was that it might have been a foreign movie, since I do remember that the character's lips didn't go in sync with their voices so I guess that it was translated to Swedish, but I have no idea if it's from US, UK, elsewhere in Europe, or even Australia.

So if there is anyone who knows where this scene comes from, please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: That sounds much more likely to be an episode of a television show than a movie.